# Can we automate SAP application ? if yes which automation tool we can use?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, automation, sap, hp-uft, tosca

we are planning to Automate the SAP application (Tier -1) and we want to automate, can expert guide here what are that automation tools we use, among all which be best to use?

Comment: Probably. First of all, you should give more details, what you tried, tell which SAP software you are talking about, etc. You know, SAP is 3rd software company in the world, 1st being Microsoft, so asking "can we automate Microsoft application" is not very precise...

Comment: did you do any research at all? you don't think you are the first people to automate SAP applications, dont you?.. why all available resource do not satisfy you?

Comment: Proposing to close this question, it needs details/clarity, and it's likely to be answered with opinions rather than facts and citations. See [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help).

Answer (score 0):

Sap has a built in transaction to record 'pattern'. You can adjust it - it generates code in vbs. Well, unless the basis team blocked this possibility.

T-code: SHDB